# Unable to parse yaml file into python

Tags: python, parsing, yaml

I am trying to parse data from a simple YAML file into python however running the program generates an error.

## File.py

#!/usr/bin/env python3

import yaml

with open ('xyz.yml', 'r') as handle:

```
try:
    print("File opened")
    data = yaml.full_load(handle)
    print("data loaded")
    print(data)
except yaml.YAMLError as error:
    print(error)
```

YAML file contains as below.

## xyz.yml

---

name: nick # YAML allows comments
things:
-chair
-table

- sofa:
  color: gray
  age: 2

However, running the program

➜  PYTHON python3 file.py
File opened
mapping values are not allowed here
in "xyz.yml", line 9, column 9

Anything wrong with syntax or code? The same data works with JSON. I have tried the same code with JSON Data, of course with JSON structure data and loading the JSON library and necessary JSON calls in the python program

Comment: YAML Data is as below, in previous update it did not structured so updating it again.
---
name: nick # YAML allows comments
things:
  -chair
  -table
  - sofa:
    color: gray
    age: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is with your YAML file I believe, it should've been:

```
name: nick # YAML allows comments
things:
  - chair
  - table
  - sofa:
      color: gray
      age: 2
```

YAML depends a lot on indentation so keep that in mind.